# What happened to Duffy?

Tags: where-are-they-now

Does anybody know what happened to Duffy? Her last album was released five years ago, hardly any live performance the last years, too.

Any news for a new album? Or did she just give up?

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffy_%28singer%29#2011.E2.80.93present:_Hiatus.2C_third_studio_album.2C_and_return_to_acting):

> At the 2014 Cannes Film Festival, it was announced that Duffy would
>   return to acting with a starring role in the film *Secret Love*, and
>   would contribute to its soundtrack.

She might want to focus more on acting than on singing.

Comment: That was last I heard too - but neither Duffy's nor Niall Johnson's page shows that as even being to pre-production/script yet [including on IMDB Pro which lists more than the public version]

Answer (score 1):

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2921190/) she has been working (since 2015):

- As an actress in the movie [Legend](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3569230), playing **Timi Yuro**.
- As a sountrack writer in the movie Legend, writing *Whole Lotta Love*.
- As a soundtrack singer in the movie Legend, singing *Whole Lotta Love*, *Are You Sure*, *Make the World Go Away*